# Possible to use extra IP on Windows Server as proxy in C#?

Tags: c#, proxy, ip, windows-server, static-ip-address

On our VPS we can buy extra IP, and add them to Windows server like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmzfa.jpg]

So I want to know if we can use these IPs as proxy?
I want to use them as proxy in C#.
So I use it like this:

```
HttpClientHandler aHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
IWebProxy proxy = new MyProxy(new Uri("http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx"));
proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxxx", "xxxx");
aHandler.Proxy = proxy;
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(aHandler);
```

My main question is how to use extra IP added to server as proxy and then use in the code (C#)?